# Need help on SQL query - Select data with duplicate multiple data entries in one data field

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select all data having non-duplicate IDs..
here's my sample table..

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID        | Zip-Code       | Search Query        | ID_LIST
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         | 1000           | Query Sample 1      | 13,14,15,
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2         | 2000           | Query Sample 2      | 16,13,17,
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3         | 3000           | Query Sample 3      | 18,17,13,
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4         | 4000           | Query Sample 4      | 15,16,17,18,
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5         | 5000           | Query Sample 5      | 19, 20,
```

u can notice that IDs 1 and 2 have duplicate, which is 13 on ID_LIST

2 and 3 also have duplicate, which is 13 and 17.

What I want to do is make it like this...

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID        | Zip-Code       | Search Query        | ID_LIST
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         | 1000           | Query Sample 1      | 13,14,15,
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2         | 2000           | Query Sample 2      | 16,17,
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3         | 3000           | Query Sample 3      | 18,
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5         | 5000           | Query Sample 5      | 19,20,
```

What query would be good for this? Any Help?

Comment: Why isn't 1 just 14,15, ?

Comment: 13 on ID_LIST is entered in ID no.2, so I dont want to include it in ID no.2

Comment: [**Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: You not only do select but also do update. Is it what you want in one query ?

Comment: @Dere0405 yes, yes, select and update query..

Comment: Yes. Normalise your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to approach it is to `normalize` your data, as mentioned in comments. But if you absolutely have to do it this way, it would be very difficult to do in query on mysql.

I would suggest you to create a **procedure** for it. As and when you develop each step, you can google that particular solution of that step, and test it and build up on that. Let me know if any step sound confusing/unclear.

1. Create a variable string, say `v_vals`. Initialize with null. At the end of procedure, it will contain all the distinct values of `id_list` (`13`,`14`...`20`)
2. Iterate through each row.
3. Count the number of comma in `id_list`.
4. Loop from 1 to number of comma.
5. In every iteration, use `substring` and `instring` to find position of each comma and then extract values from `id_list`. (`13`,`14`...)
6. use another variable `v_id_list`. Put null in it.
7. Search for the values (from step 5) in `v_vals`. If they exist in `v_val`, then skip them, else put them in `v_val` and `v_id_list`.
8. Now run an update statement to update `id_list` with `v_id_list`.

Now repeat Step `3` to `8` for each row.

9. Note that `v_id_list` will be reinitialize for each loop, however `v_val` will contain all the distinct values of `id_list`.